# Lumen PDO Driver not found

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, pdo

I am running Lumen on Nginx, PHP 5.6 ec2.

I get this error when I try to make a db query.

```
PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
could not find driver
```

This is my .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=appkey

APP_LOCALE=en
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=en

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mydb****.cdsfsdf***.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD= password

CACHE_DRIVER=memcached
SESSION_DRIVER=memcached
QUEUE_DRIVER=database

# MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
# MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
# MAIL_PORT=2525
# MAIL_USERNAME=null
# MAIL_PASSWORD=null
# MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
# MAIL_FROM_NAME=null

# FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
# FILESYSTEM_CLOUD=s3

# S3_KEY=null
# S3_SECRET=null
# S3_REGION=null
# S3_BUCKET=null

# RACKSPACE_USERNAME=null
# RACKSPACE_KEY=null
# RACKSPACE_CONTAINER=null
# RACKSPACE_REGION=null
```

How can I fix this? The code works perfectly fine my localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if php-mysql module was installed.

```
rpm -q php-mysql -l
```

If not installed run this command:

```
yum install php56-mysqlnd
```